# UIImageView draw in rect with size of image and not image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I want to draw on `UIImageView`, following is my code for drawing. My image view mode is aspect fit. When i draw using the following code, since i am using `drawinrect` and giving the rect of `UIImageView` so all the images are scaled down to the size to the `imageview. I want to draw the image of size of image and not image view.Since i am detecting the touch point on the imageview so the point of tap and actual drawing on image is different. Can any body tell me how to draw on image directly. and how to calculate this shift or difference in the point of touch on image rather than image view.

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];

 }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

CGPoint   currentTouch = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.image.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.image.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];

CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, _brushSize);

CGContextBeginPath(context) ;

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,currentTouch.x,currentTouch.y) ;

CGContextSetAlpha( context , 1 );

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_brushColor CGColor]);

CGContextStrokePath(context) ;

self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastTouch = currentTouch;


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be us classing `UIImageView`. It isn't intended to be subclassed.

A better approach to this would be to have a `UIView` instead of the `UIImageView`.

Then two possible ways is to either...

Draw the `UIImage` directly into the `UIView` inside drawRect but this will give you the same problem that you are currently having.

Or...

In the `UIView` have a `UIImageView`. Resize this so that it is the correct size/shape for the `UIImage`. (Ie do the scaling yourself) then over the `UIImageView` put a second `UIView` (and subclass this) this second one will be capped DrawingView or something. You can now do all your drawing inside here. And all your touch detection will be in here too. So you no longer need to convert the touch points into different drawing points.

Comment: Thanks for the edits :D was written on my iPhone so couldn't format it at the time.